# Arcpy cannot find shapefile attribute

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, numpy

I want arcpy to perform the following: load a shapefile, prepare to edit it, open its attribute table, perform a numpy.digitize using the values of a certain attribute and some bins provided separately.
My  code looks like this:

```
network = r"C:\Mylocation\MyShapefile.shp" 

intersected = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(network, ["DIAMETER", "Other_Attributes_I_Will_Need_Later"])

bins = [ bin1, bin2, bin3, ... binn]

cats = numpy.digitize(intersected.DIAMETER, bins)
```

But this way I receive the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'DIAMETER'. I guess the problem is that it my code does not "dig" into intersected to find the values I need, but therefore how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You've missed several steps in proper DA cursor use. Please review the examples in the documentation.

Comment: You can also go straight to a numpy array. See TableToNumpyArray examples here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000018000000

Comment: Please include the precise error message that you receive from running any code that you present here.  That should include the line number on which the error occurs.